# Can I force two XML elements to be on the same line when using System.Xml classes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, formatting

Suppose I have the following XML built using System.Xml.XmlElement objects.

```
<person>
    <first>Bob</first>
    <last>Jones</last>
    <phone>5556667777</phone>
</person>
```

Is there a way I can force two tags to be on the same line? I want it to look like this at the end.

```
<person>
    <first>Bob</first><last>Jones</last>
    <phone>5556667777</phone>
</person>
```

I want to be able to search for names occasionally in my final XML export file. I'm grateful that .NET takes care of the formatting for me, but I'd like to make an exception in this case (without resorting to manually outputting all the XML myself).

Comment: Why not use XML Notepad and Xquery for your search in the output? Since you're making a structured document, leverage the structure...

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni - Fair question. That would help me as a technical user (and I will look into that). I just work with support reps who would have no hope of using such tech unless I wrote a special app/tool specifically for searching.

Comment: Adding a redundant  field `fullname` ?

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw seems to me that a little custom search/filter support tool would be more useful than the trivial structural change.... but you're closer to the use cases you're trying to satisfy than we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want to code a Regex replace routine on your output?

Comment: This is probably the most practical solution given my circumstances. The other suggestions are good, but I cannot fundamentally alter the structure of the document. So, filtering the final output seems like my only option.